# Taking information from logs using grep, sed, awk and cut

Tags: text-processing, awk, logs, cut

I'm trying to use simple commands to extract data from a log file.

Here's a sample line from the file

```
128.101.35.183 - - [23/Mar/2008:00:03:10 +0000] "GET /javascript/email.js HTTP/1.1" 200 359 "http://www.cs.ucd.ie/Staff/AcademicStaff/bsmyth/"; "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.12) Gecko/20080201 Firefox/2.0.0.12"
```

How can I get the date and time of the first and last log entry to the file displayed in the following format:

23/Mar/2008:00:03:10

with no other characters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this to get the timestamps from the first and last lines in your log file:

```
{ head -n 1 my_log_file; tail -n 1 my_log_file; } | awk '{print $4}' | tr -d '['
```

As an aside, this looks like an Apache log, and you may wish to look into using [Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash) to parse your structured logs.

Comment: Nice, but you might replace the `head; tail` bit with `sed -n '1p;$p'` for greater simplicity and speed.  It will only open the file once instead of twice, and doesn't need shell braces to combine commands.

Comment: @Wildcard: it only runs one process, but it reads the whole file whereas `tail` seeks to the last block-or-so; this is faster if the logfile is very large, and logfiles sometimes are very large, especially the ones you need to look at when there's a problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F"[][]" 'NR==1{sub(" .*","",$2);print $2}END{sub(" .*","",$2);print $2}' logfile
```